# Understanding acronyms in detailed output on Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility

**Background**

I wanted to zero my USB drive. I first tried using dd and it was running horrificly slowly ~ 2MB/s on my 32GB drive, so I tried using the Disk Utility app and it was much faster even over 2 full passes (I didn't note down the speed, rookie, and now I can't find a log for it).

**Question**

Please could someone explain the acronyms in the detailed output that I got from Disk Utility?

**Output**

```
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk2s1: 60056896 sectors in 1876778 FAT32 clusters (16384 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=32 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf8 spt=32 hds=255 hid=2048 drv=0x80 bsec=60086272 bspf=14663 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=6
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/toolbox/newfs_msdos.c?

Comment: I assume it is some information about the newly created FAT filesystem.